# What is the most efficient way to encode a character ? (with regards to memory)

Tags: c, encoding

I have 4 characters that I want to encode: 
Is there a way to give them an "encoded version", instead of ASCII? Binary would be the best but I have only 0 and 1 for the binary, and if I would then use the sequence it wouldn't be clear which character is 0 and which 1 and which 11 for example. Is there any other way to encode efficiently, with minimum number of bits?
Thanks

Comment: Yes. There is a way and minimum number of bits. However the fact that you do not seem to understand how to do this in *any way* with "just 0 and 1" means that I do not know which one I would suggest.

Comment: With only 4 characters, 2 bits per character is enough. If you have statistics that show that one particular character appears much more often, you could increase the compacity by giving 1 bit to this characters and 3 to the others.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that I don't know, if reading the file, whether 110 means CCA or TA, since CC is 11 and T = 1. I need to be able to differentiate it if I for example want to read from the file EXACTLY how many times TGAC sequence occured...

Comment: @Joël Hecht, With only 5 characters, you need 3 bits per cahracter or a length prefix.

Comment: You used 5 in your example (T, G, A, C and space to denote the end). Again, 4 character is not enough; you need some way of knowing where the sequence ends.

Answer (score 1):

There are 4 different values. 2 bits can encode 4 values.

```
00
01
10
11
```

That means each byte can encode 4 different values.

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 4 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

For example, we could choose the following encoding scheme:

```
T = 00
G = 01
A = 10
C = 11
```

110 (0b01101110) would therefore mean ACAG (assuming the first value is found in the least significant bits).

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
 ---G--- ---A--- ---C--- ---A---
```

That's means the string would only use as little as 25% of the space used when using ASCII.

Except this doesn't quite work. There's no way to know the length of the sequence. For example, how would you encode `ACA` using the above scheme?

There are options:

1. Somehow prefix the sequence by its length.

   This could end up doubling the length of the encoded string if it's really short.
2. Introduce a 5th, sentinel value to indicate the end of the string.

   This complicates the encoding (since we no longer have a power of 2). It also reduces the compression factor (8 values per 3 bytes, so as little as 37.5% of the space used when using ASCII).
3. Use the first 2 bits of each byte to indicate how many values are actually present in the byte. This reduces the compression factor (3 values per byte, so as little as 33% of the space used when using ASCII).
4. You can can use real compression techniques (e.g. use frequency analysis to use shorter sequences to more common subsequences), probably using using zlib or a more modern equivalent. This method is very effective (perhaps even using 1/10th of what ASCII would), but it's only effective if you have very long sequences. It also prevents random access. This means that can't get the Nth value without first reading all the previous one. In short, you'd have to decode the string to ASCII to search it.

You indicates in a comment that you wanted to search the sequences for subsequences, but none of these approaches makes that easier (and the fourth one prevents it, as mentioned above). They make it very complicated, in fact. Converting the sequence to ASCII to search it is highly recommended.

Comment: I would create a struct (since C) with a byte* and an unsigned int for the length (count of nucleotides).

Comment: @Mario The Spoon, That would fall under method 1. That said, an implementation that only works in memory is a very poor choice of implementation. The compression is surely to be used when storing the sequences outside of memory because it's very hard to work on the sequences in their compressed form.

Comment: @Mario The Spoon,  Also, that approach is problematic if you have a lot of short sequences, counteracting the gains of the compression while still making it hard and slow to work with the data. That's why it was a presented as an *option*. It's not always the right answer. (But that fact that this allows an even four values per bytes makes it a very attractive option.)